# Data not getting passed to the ajax function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html-table

The form below is present in every row of an html table.However alert("dfd") pops up only for the first row of the table and not for the forms in the other rows(these forms appear on the webpage).Can anyone tell why is it happening?

HTML:

```
 <form class='form form-horizontal' method='post' role='form' id='formsel' name='formsel'>
        <fieldset  >   
        <div>    
            <span class='control-group' >
            <span  class='controls'>
                <select id='formcont' name='formcont' class='form-control' style='cursor:pointer;'>
                    <option selected='selected' style='display:none;'>Select</option>
                    <option  value='1'>Option1</option>
                    <option  value='2'>Option2</option>
                    <option  value='3'>Option3</option>

            </select> <button id='selbtn' name='selbtn' type='submit'>Sub,it</button>

            </span>
            </span></div>

        </fieldset>

    </form>
```

JS:

```
$("#formsel").submit(function () {
    alert("dfd");
    $.ajax({
        url:"add.php",
        data:$("#formcont").val().serialize(),
        type:"POST",
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
            if(data=="done"){
                alert("success");
            } 
        },
        error:function(data){
            alert("Network ERROR");
        }
    })
    return false;
});


$("#selbtn").click(function () {
  ("#formsel").submit();
});
```

PHP:

```
 <?php
    include ('db.php');
    session_start();

    echo "done";
    ?>
```

Comment: You cannot have duplicate id's in a web page. Use a class or setup unique id's `#formsel`

Comment: You have multiple ids in your code `formsel`, `formcont` and `selbtn`. Probably that's the reason why your code doesn't work

Comment: can you please tell how to setup unique ids as the html code above appears only once in a table

Comment: what happens if you change `$("#formcont").val().serialize()` to `$(".form-control").val().serialize()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, because you're not sending any data:

```
$("#formcont").val().serialize()
```

Should be:

```
$(this).serialize()
```

Since the button you're clicking to trigger the `submit` is a submit button, you really do not need the following code:

```
$("#selbtn").click(function () {
  ("#formsel").submit();
});
```

Comment: Great! Glad you have it taken care of :)